# Word order in question: "Subject is" or "is subject"?

Tags: questions, word-order

I'm brushing up rules about question word order and have one doubt. What is right word order in the question.

Context:
Mr. A and Mr. B talk to Mr. C about something. Mr. A is talking about special rules. Mr. B thinks that it may not be understandable for Mr. C. He interrupt Mr. A and say:

> What Mr. A **is** trying to say?

or

> What **is** Mr. A trying to say?

What is right word order in that sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really clear on your question, but from what I think:

> B doesn't understand something/B thinks C doesn't understand
>   something, and interrupts A, to clarify.

If this is the case, then both your sentences can fit in a given context.

For instance:

If B doesn't understand what A says, and says this to C , then this sentence would fit:

> What **is** Mr. A trying to say?

If B doesn't understand what A says, and B expresses this to C, **along with some other meaning too**, then this sentence would fit:

> What Mr. A is trying to say **doesn't make sense**.

The reason I added **along with some other meaning too** is because the following sentence doesn't stand on its own, and needs some additional meaning to it:

> What Mr. A is trying to say?

If my answer doesn't explicitly answer your question(s), perhaps you could edit and reword it to make the situation clear.

Comment: But your answer contains it implictly. Thanks :).

Comment: BTW, I think that the first example that I cited is more natural in the `B doesn't understand something/B thinks C doesn't understand something, and interrupts A, to clarify`. Unfortunately I cannot explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask the question like this:

> **Do you understand** what Mr. A is trying to say?

You can also ask:

> What is Mr. A trying to say?

However, that question isn't necessarily asking about comprehension; it could simply be asking for a paraphrase.

For example:

> **Mr A**: We went out to lunch and I left 10 euros on my desk. Now they're gone.
>   **Mr B**: What is Mr. A trying to say?
>   **Mr C**: Someone stole his 10 euros.

or,

> **Mr A**: We went out to lunch and I left 10 euros on my desk. Now they're gone.
>   **Mr B**: Do you understand what Mr. A is trying to say?
>   **Mr C**: Yes. Someone stole his 10 euros.

Both questions are valid, but notice how the word *is* has moved.